# set Default format of phone number in salesforce from web to lead

Tags: web2lead

In web to lead concept, From website Phone numbers come in mostly as 0123456789, this needs to save default to 0123 456 789 in salesforce.
Also, the name store in salesforce from web to lead, in which first letter should be capital.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

To build in validations and formatting in your web to lead form, you have to do some css styling and client side coding e.g. Javascript. You may find some interesting Javascript recipies for field formatting and validations on code.activestate.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1) Write some javascript on the web form to validate the phone number

2) Write logic on the Salesforce end - perhaps an APEX trigger or a workflow

Comment: Hi Boris, As i am new to salesforce, so can you explain How to Write logic on the Salesforce end - perhaps an APEX trigger or a workflow .

Comment: Check out the developers guide on triggers - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm and workflows - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wf.htm&language=en_US